# petstore URL not disabled in SpringDoc OpenAPi

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui, springdoc-ui

I am using `SpringDoc 1.4.3` for swagger. 
I have added the below configuration to disabled the `petstore` URLs in `application.yml`

**Configuration**

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    disable-swagger-default-url: true
    tags-sorter: alpha
    operations-sorter: alpha
    doc-expansion: none
```

but when I hit the https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json in explore text box, it is still showing me the petsore URLs as shown in the below image.

**Swagger Image**

[image: Swagger Image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Already tested and validated thanks to the following feature support:

- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/714

Just use, the following property:

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.disable-swagger-default-url=true
```

Comment: yet that is working,
but if we add the URL `https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json ` explicitly in explore textbox then it is still showing. as shown in the attached screen shot

Comment: You should block it in your firewall rules, if you want to block Access. Petstore URL is like any other urls.

Comment: add that property for your default API docs URL: springdoc.swagger-ui.url=/v1/api-docs

Answer (score 7):

For those if the suggested property setting did not work, clear the browser cache and reload the URL. The property setting DOES WORK. Wasted 2 hours to figure it out.

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    disable-swagger-default-url: true
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had an incorrectly-defined servlet filter - I was missing a 'return;' statement. This caused the filter chain to not be processed properly, and some of the Swagger requests got borked.

Check to see if you have the following condition:

```java
@Component
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (some condition) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);

            return;    /**** Don't forget this line! ****/
        }

        ... more logic ...

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly the cause that I had.

Answer (score -1):

The only way I got around this was by adding a SwaggerConfig page [[tutorial here](https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api)] and changing to OAS_3 and saving, and then you can either change it to something else after.

```
return new Docket(DocumentationType.OAS_30)
```

It just seems like Swagger is keeping a cache or something, but saving a configured OAS_3 seems to let Swagger know to stop using the default.

Comment: The question is about Springdoc, and this answer about Springfox.

Answer (score -6):

Set below property, this will disable Swagger OpenApi 3 UI module

```
springdoc.api-docs.enabled=false
```

Comment: It disables the whole swagger ui