# Why the springdoc always show the petshop Swagger UI

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger

I am trying to integrete the [spring doc](https://springdoc.org/#migrating-from-springfox) into my spring boot project. First, I added the dependencies

```
api "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.9"
api "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core:1.2.32"
```

then access the swagger ui: http://127.0.0.1:11014/swagger-ui/index.html#/. Now I facing a problem is that no matter how to tweak the  open api swagger config, the swagger ui always show the petshop api. I have tried to add config like this

```java
package misc.config.openapi;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.ExternalDocumentation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.Info;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.License;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfig {

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI openAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .info(new Info()
                        .title("Student Manager API")
                        .description("Student manager server api.API.")
                        .version("appVersion")
                        .license(new License()
                                .name("Apache2.0")
                                .url("http://springdoc.org")))
                .externalDocs(new ExternalDocumentation()
                        .description("Documentation")
                        .url("https://www.jianshu.com/nb/41542276"));
    }

}
```

Why the spring docs always show the petshop api? how to make the swagger ui show the project api not the demo petshop version?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63152653/petstore-url-not-disabled-in-springdoc-openapi